# Remove short words and characters from a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string which could be like this:

```
$searchterm = "The quick brown fox, jumps over the lazy dog! 48372. John's?"
```

Is there a way to remove all words that are 3 characters and under as well as characters that aren't alphanumeric (except for apostrophes)?

I want my result to be:

```
quick brown jumps over lazy 48372 John's
```

Comment: Of course there is. What have you thought of so far as a way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = trim( preg_replace(
    "/[^a-z0-9']+([a-z0-9']{1,3}[^a-z0-9']+)*/i",
    " ",
    " $searchterm "
) );
```

BTW, if you want the words in an array, there's an even simpler solution:

```
preg_match_all( "/[a-z0-9']{4,}/i", $searchterm, $words );
$words = $words[0];
```

Of course, you can use `implode()` and `explode()` to convert between the two output formats.

Comment: And here I was messing round with explode and string counts.. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this..

```
/* remove the non alphanumeric except for quotes */
$searchterm = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\' ]/i', '', $searchterm);

/* remove <= three letter words */
$searchterm = preg_replace('/(^| )[a-z0-9\']{,3}( |$)/i', ' ', $searchterm);
```

Comment: Your code will cause an error due to the `/ig`. The first line removes all spaces and capital letters. Try `[^A-Za-z0-9\' ]` Also, you must have `A-Za-z` or `A-z` or it will ignore all capital letters...

Comment: The `i` wont, I threw g in there as I am used to the vim syntax of search replace :), `i` makes it case insensitive, I did miss the space though, thanks :)

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the `i` works in PHP. Yeah, switching between javascript and PHP does that to me all the time.